# What's wrong in this proof of 1=2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

Here is the proof:

```
let a = b
a² = ab
a²-b² = ab-b²
(a-b)(a+b) = b(a-b)
a+b = b
2b = b
2 = 1
```

Now, of course Problem must lie on the line `(a-b)(a+b) = b(a-b)`, as it seems like multiplying by 0 on both side but does algebraic rule allow that step? Anyway, where is the error in this proof?

Comment: $a-b=0$, you can't go from $(a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b)$ to $a+b=b$

Comment: Is there any law that particularly forbid this?

Comment: You can see that $1\times 0=2\times 0$, can't you? But that doesn't mean that $1=2$. (And yes, there is a law that particularly forbids this: you can't divide by zero.)

Comment: Yes, dividing by $0$ is not well-defined in general.

Comment: $ac=bc \implies a=b$ only if $c$ is not a zero divisor. Think about it, the equation says $0=0$. You cannot do $0=2\times 0=1\times 0 \implies 2=1$.